# Turning a react Native into html5 /PWA

Tags: html, react-native, frontend, progressive-web-apps, migrating

I wanted to know if there is any way I migrate a react native app into a website format without having to rebuild a new frontend (Html5, PWA...).

Has anyone done it or knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you made use of in your project. There are a few projects that are dedicated to allowing a RN app to be built for a browser target ([react-native-web being one example](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)) however this only covers some of the scope of what's possible, so if you've used anything outside this scope you'll need to rewrite these parts.